# How to pass lambda as intent to start an activity in android using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am writing a library that allow user to start my activity with pass in params and callbacks.

The architecture I been following is the MVVM. I dont have any issue with the MVVM pattern however, I am running into an occasional issue with the callback pass in from my caller.

```
   class mainActivity :Activity { 
   
// standard lifecycle
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
     ...
    }

    override fun onResume() {
    // here I am accessing the static callback from companion object. 
    // but sometimes I am getting lateinit property callback has not been initialized 
    //exception.  
    callback.invoke()
    }
   
   companion object {
   lateinit var callback: () -> Unit
    
    
    //user will call my library from this method and provide me the callback 
    fun play( 
       callback: () -> Unit
    ){
      callback = callback // here I assigned the callback so that my activity can use it later. 
     }
   }
}
```

inside `onResume` I am accessing the callback. sometimes I am getting

`lateinit property callback has not been initialized`

however, I am not available to reproduce it 100% at all. What can be an issue? can you please shed some lights with me please?

Comment: You will crash with that error when the user restarts your app after [process death](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states). And you will crash with that error if the developer using your library fails to call `play()`. In addition, your approach will have problems if the developer using your library wants to start multiple instances of your activity. I recommend that you explore other approaches (allowing your activity to be subclassed, or using something other than an activity as the primary exposed API).

Comment: @CommonsWare I am interest in the "something other than an activity as the primary exposed API" part. My library has a UI displaying something to user and once user click on my UI, i will need to callback for caller's actions. What's your recommend ways to do so?

Comment: Using a fragment would be a lot more flexible, for you and for the developer who is interested in displaying your UI. Depending on the size/scope of that UI, you could also consider a custom view. And, if you want to be "cutting edge", you could publish your UI as a composable implemented using Jetpack Compose.